# JQuery submit button doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code but it doesn't fire or doesn't show any error when I click on the save button. Could you please let me know what could be the problem? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[id*=btnSave]').click(function () {
    var txtFirstName = $('input[id*=txtFirstName]').val();
    var txtLastName = $('input[id*=txtLastName]').val();
    var errMsg = '';
    var errMsg = "<ul>";
    if (txtFirstName == '') {
      errMsg = errMsg + "<li>First Name is required</li>";
      return false;
    }
    if (txtLastName == '') {
      errMsg = errMsg + "<li>Last Name is required</li>";
      return false;
    }
    errMsg = errMsg + "</ul>";
  });
});
</script>

<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" />
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: where is `btnSave_Click` function

Comment: that means you want to implement multiple process on submit button click?

Answer (score 1):

I think you selector line needs to have quotes around the id value:

```
$('input[id*="btnSave"]').click(function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
$('input#btnSave').click(function() {

});
```

is enough.

don't need to use

```
$('input[id*=btnSave]')
```

and where is your `btnSave_Click` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnSave').click(function () {

                    var txtFirstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
                    var txtLastName = $('#txtLastName').val();
                    var errMsg = '';
                    var errMsg = "<ul>";
                    if (txtFirstName == '') {
                        errMsg = errMsg + "<li>First Name is required</li>";
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (txtLastName == '') {
                        errMsg = errMsg + "<li>Last Name is required</li>";
                        return false;
                    }
                errMsg = errMsg + "</ul>";
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use

```
$('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function ()
```

Comment: the <asp:Button> is going to generate <input type='sumbit' ...> but the id is going to be set to something like "ctl100_btnSave" depending upon how deeply the button itself is nested in other server controls, like master pages and so on. the reason the example in the answer works is because the ClientID property is the value you set (btnSave) and matches the variable name in the code behind. Your original code would work, I think your wildcarding is wrong is all.